# Is there a cleaner way to handle null checking now that the ? test exists for a variable?

Tags: c#

My code currently looks like this:

```
if (control != null && control.Meta != null && control.State != null)
{
   ConfigureMeta(control, control.Meta);
   ConfigureColors(control, control.State);
}
```

Is there now another cleaner way that I could do this null check using the "?" that was added to the latest version of C#?

Comment: It was added about 4 years ago, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Please read about [Null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators). There is nothing wrong with your code. Of course if you have `null` checking inside your methods, it can be writen as `ConfigureMeta(control, control?.Meta);` or `ConfigureColors(control, control?.State);`, but in this case, using `?` will not change anything too much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the *null-conditional operator* (*C#6*) to reduce one check - added (July 2015)

[null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

> Tests the value of the left-hand operand for null before performing a
>   member access (`?.`) or index (`?[]`) operation; returns `null` if the
>   left-hand operand evaluates to null.

```
if (control?.Meta != null && control?.State != null)
{
}
```

if you really really really want to make multiple checks easier and you have printable character *OCD* (and you just like writing methods for the fun of it)

You could use the following

```
public bool CheckAll(params object[] refs) => refs.All(x => x != null);

...

if (CheckAll(control?.Meta, control?.State))
{
}
```